# Adding two ajax modal popup in a single page

Tags: c#, ajax

I encountered a problem where i add two ajax modal popup in a single page. This two modal popup each do different things. one is is create and one is for update. When two modal popup, my update button cannot be click ans execute the update codes. And when i remove my create modal popup, my updates work? Can anyone tell me how do i make two popup exist in the same page?

```
<!--Modal Popup: Create Topic-->
        <cc1:modalpopupextender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" 
        TargetControlID="btnShowPopup" PopupControlID="pnlCreatePopup" 
        CancelControlID="btnCancel" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
        </cc1:modalpopupextender>

        <asp:Panel ID="pnlCreatePopup" runat="server"  CssClass="createModalPopup">


<!--Modal Popup: Update Topic-->
    <asp:Button ID="bnUpdateShow" runat="server" style="display:none;" />

        <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="bnUpdateShow" PopupControlID="pnlpopup" CancelControlID="btnUpdateCancel" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
        </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>

    <asp:Panel ID="pnlpopup" runat="server" CssClass="topicModalPopup">
```

Comment: I don't think you can.  That would be like having two textbox's having focus at the same time.

Comment: I've put two modal popups on one page using jquery tools overlay -- http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html. Of course, you cannot have two modals displayed at the same time because the definition of "modal" includes the stipulation that there can be only one at a time. My 2 popups are displayed at different times on the same page.

Comment: popup at different time. but still can't

Comment: did u get any javascript error when u run the page? if yes plz share it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this hiding the ajax pop up inside a panel configured as visible=false. I fire the popUp in codeBehind. here is some code:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbCredits1" Font-Underline="true" 
        CausesValidation="false" OnClick="btMpeCredits_Click">Credits</asp:LinkButton>
        &nbsp;|&nbsp;
       <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbPrivacy2" Font-Underline="true" 
        CausesValidation="false" OnClick="btMpePrivacy_Click">Privacy</asp:LinkButton>

<%--AjaxPopUpExtenderArea--%>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlAjaxArea" runat="server" Visible="false">
<%--PrivacyMPE--%>
    <%--I have to hide the link button referenced in the AjaxPopUpExtender. I will use a different button to show the pop up--%>
    <div style="display:none;">
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbPrivacy" Text="PRIVACY"/>
    </div>
        <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="MpePrivacy" runat="server" TargetControlID="lbPrivacy"
            PopupControlID="PnlPrivacy" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" >
        </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="PnlPrivacy" Height="500px" Width="600px" BorderStyle="Solid"
            BorderColor="#1E549E" BorderWidth="3px" BackColor="#FFFFFF" ScrollBars="Auto">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <UcPrivacy:Privacy runat="server" ID="Privacy" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/GfRegistrationPage/images/chiudi-btn.gif" runat="server" OnClick="btMpeClose"
                            CausesValidation="False" />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </asp:Panel>
<%--CreditsMPE--%>
    <div style="display:none;">
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbCredits" Text="credits"/>
    </div>
        <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="MpeCredits" runat="server" TargetControlID="lbCredits"
            PopupControlID="PnlCredits" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" >
        </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="PnlCredits" Height="500px" Width="600px" BorderStyle="Solid"
            BorderColor="#1E549E" BorderWidth="3px" BackColor="#FFFFFF" ScrollBars="Auto">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <UcCredits:Credits runat="server" ID="Credits" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/GfRegistrationPage/images/chiudi-btn.gif" runat="server" OnClick="btMpeClose"
                            CausesValidation="False" />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </asp:Panel>
</asp:Panel>
```

and here some code behind:

```
    #region ModalPopUpS Privacy credits
protected void btMpePrivacy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnlAjaxArea.Visible = true;
    AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender modalPop = ((AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender)(this.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("MpePrivacy")));
    modalPop.Show();
}
protected void btMpeCredits_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnlAjaxArea.Visible = true;
    AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender modalPop = ((AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender)(this.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("MpeCredits")));
    modalPop.Show();
}
protected void btMpeClose(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnlAjaxArea.Visible = false;
}
#endregion
```